# How to use output buffering ob_start in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, ob-start

I have been trying to implement caching via out buffers. I have used that approach in PHP but I am stuck as where to start buffering i.e. 
(1). where to put ob_start() in controller
(2). How to send buffer data to views

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> (1). where to put ob_start() in controller

No where. The `View` class already uses output buffering.

> (2). How to send buffer data to views

You don't. The `View` is supposed to generate the response for you. You set required view vars from controller that are needed by View to generate the response.